# Asymptotic Efficiency of Two-Stage Least Squares

Tags: econometrics, asymptotics, instrumental-variables, proof, 2sls

Apparently Wooldridge, [Introductory Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0324660545), 2002ed is the only book showing that two-stage least squares (2SLS) is asymptotically efficient. I cannot get a copy of the proof.

Is it correct to just use the generalized method of moments (GMM) proof substituting in the instrumental variables?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the key is to use homoscedasticity so that the GMM weight matrix simplifies.  Given that, a bit of cancellation will show that the variance of the optimal GMM estimator reduces to the 2SLS variance.