# proof FGLS asymptotically efficient

Tags: self-study, asymptotics, proof, generalized-least-squares

Prove that FGLS  is asymptotically efficient. Does one have to use Cramer Rao to do this?

Comment: Homework tag too?

Comment: I presume that FGLS stands for "Feasible GLS". Is this question related to your preceding question, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23700/930?

Comment: yes feasible GLS. I'm unsure at which stage the proof should end, in class our lecturer ends with "it can be shown that" _ is asymp efficient. And I'm uncertain whether in proving it it is necessary to calculate the Cramer Rao variance as part of the proof that it is the min var estimator of Beta.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "No."  Some hints for an approach:  FGLS is closely related to another estimator, which can be shown to be asymptotically efficient (w/o using Cramer-Rao.)  I'm  sure you've covered it already in your class.  Under what conditions does the asymptotic dist'n of FGLS converge to that of the other estimator?  (They aren't terribly restrictive.)

Note that FGLS isn't guaranteed to be asymptotically efficient; if I use an estimate of the covariance matrix that isn't consistent, then FGLS won't even be consistent.  So some conditions (relating to what?) are required for asymptotic efficiency.

Comment: It has the same asymptotic properties as GLS if the weighted sum of squares matrix based on the Omega converges to a positive definite matrix (then estimated gamma also converges to the same matrix,) and if it has a limiting normal distribution.

Comment: What are "Omega" and "gamma"?  Don't forget, not everybody uses the same notation... Regardless, the "limiting normal distribution" isn't a necessary condition, it's more of a result.

Comment: where Omega is the variable in the covariance matrix (heteroskedastic)

Comment: You can construct cases where $X^T\widehat{\Omega}^{-1}X/N$ converging to a pds matrix isn't enough; it has to converge to a particular pds matrix.  Also, there's another condition involving the errors that is analogous to one you see in proofs relating to OLS.

Comment: @jbowman Could you clarify what particular pds matrix it has to converge to?

Comment: @bob - $X^T\Omega^{-1}X/N$.